# How can I load an apk dependency from the android market?

Tags: java, android

I'm using google moderator as a simple way to collect feedback for my application. There's a google moderator app on the market that provides a better interface than the website for mobile users.

Getting to the point: Is there a way to get it to install along with your application or a reasonable way to identify if another package is available so I can direct users to the market to download it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get it to install
>   along with your application

Not automatically, no.

> a reasonable way to identify if
>   another package is available

Use `PackageManager`. Create the `Intent` you would use to start the third-party activity and use `queryIntentActivities()` on `PackageManager`. If you get an empty list back, nothing is installed that will respond to your `Intent`.